# ObjC class_addMethod does not check argument type?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation Foo

+ (void)test
{
    [Foo performSelector:@selector(foo)];
    [Foo performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:@"works"];
    [Foo performSelector:@selector(foo1)];
    [Foo performSelector:@selector(foo2)];
}

+ (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel
{
     NSLog(@"resolveClassMethod: %@", NSStringFromSelector(sel));
    if (sel == @selector(foo)) {
        class_addMethod(objc_getMetaClass("Foo"), sel, (IMP)fooIMP_withoutArgument, "s@#@@@");
        return YES;
    } else if (sel == @selector(foo1)) {
        class_addMethod(objc_getMetaClass("Foo"), sel, (IMP)fooIMP_with1Argument, "Works");
        return YES;
    } else if (sel == @selector(foo2)) {
        class_addMethod(objc_getMetaClass("Foo"), sel, (IMP)fooIMP_with2Arguments, "Not Works");
        return YES;
    }
    return [super resolveClassMethod:sel];
}

void fooIMP_withoutArgument(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    NSLog(@"fooIMP_withoutArgument");
}

void fooIMP_with1Argument(id self, SEL _cmd, id arg)
{
    NSLog(@"fooIMP_with1Argument");
}

void fooIMP_with2Arguments(id self, SEL _cmd, id arg1, id arg2)
{
    NSLog(@"fooIMP_with2Argument");
}

@end
```

Output is:

```
2018-02-27 16:41:31.638693+0800 Test[74840:2194481] resolveInstanceMethod: foo
2018-02-27 16:41:31.639201+0800 Test[74840:2194481] fooIMP_withoutArgument
2018-02-27 16:41:31.639228+0800 Test[74840:2194481] fooIMP_withoutArgument
2018-02-27 16:41:31.639490+0800 Test[74840:2194481] resolveInstanceMethod: foo1
2018-02-27 16:41:31.639519+0800 Test[74840:2194481] fooIMP_with1Argument
2018-02-27 16:41:31.639548+0800 Test[74840:2194481] resolveInstanceMethod: foo2
(lldb)
```

1. `class_addMethod` function does not check argument types?
2. Is the selector just a key point to the implementation without other role?
3. Why `IMP` with 1 argument work, but 2 arguments not?
4. How it works when call a method with params (or not) but IMP without params (or has)

Can someone help me explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

> class_addMethod function does not check argument types?

It does not. Being a dynamic-typed language, Objective-C are all essentially just `id` at runtime—the type checking for objects occurs at compile-time, and that information is not preserved in the binary. `class_addMethod` is a low-level runtime function, and as such it does not include any type checking. This is okay, since these runtime functions are meant to be very rarely used, and only in cases where you know exactly what you're doing, and therefore, what types to expect.

> SEL is just a key point to IMP without other role?

`SEL` is a selector, which in the typical implementations of Objective-C is a string, under the hood. `objc_msgSend` resolves this selector to an `IMP`, which is just a function whose body contains the method's implementation.

> Why IMP with 1 argument work, but 2 arguments not?

Since you don't show us the signature of `foo2`, nor describe what's exactly going wrong, it's difficult to say. But since it appears that you don't try to call `foo2` with any arguments, it's not too surprising that the effect would end up being something other than what you want.

Also, you're not returning `YES` after you add the methods, but calling `super`'s implementation of `resolveInstanceMethod:`. If that method happens to return `NO`, the runtime is going to think that adding the method didn't work. You should return `YES` instead after successfully adding a method. (And in the case where you don't, you should call `super`'s implementation of `resolveClassMethod:` rather than `resolveInstanceMethod:`.)

Answer (score 0):

1. No, there is generally no argument type checking during run-time.
2. A selector is just the name for a method. It is represented by just a constant C string. If you add a method to a class the selector acts like a key in a dictionary with implementations as values.
3. Adding methods with arbitrary number of arguments work fine. Your example might fail, because the `types` parameter is wrong, and the argument number in the selector doesn't match. Fix these issues first.